# Installing bolt CMS and running default theme

Tags: php, bolt-cms

I have installed bolt CMS exactly as descriped here on **[THIS](https://docs.bolt.cm/installation-composer)** page in the video tutorial. I.E. i just use the compose install command after i navgate to the folder i want the cms to be installed in , now after the CMS is installed, and i navigate to the home page, i am asked to create a user, which i do .

Now when i navigate to the homepage i get the following the homepage displays , but if i click on any of the sublinks on the homepage of the default theme i get the following screen:

[image]

Now i have seen that the .htccess file needs to be tweaked in some circumstances see **[HERE](https://docs.bolt.cm/installation#apache-tweaking-htaccess-file)**. But i am not entirely sure why i am not able to successfully install and run Bolt-CMS ? can anybody explain ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've set up Bolt correctly, but that page simply does not exists, or it's set to 'draft'.

To remedy this, make sure you have a page with id # 3, and if it exists, check the status is set to 'published'.